# Grease pencil drawing is fully on top of my 3D object after rendering while in Camera view it looks different

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil, 2d

I was trying out the Grease Pencil on a 3D object. I made some layers, they all looked perfect in viewport. But when I rendered the image the Grease Pencil drawing came fully above my 3D object while I had set it up that some parts are hidden in some dimensions.

Comment: without seeing any of your settings or results...we can just guess. So pls improve your question by showing settings, result, and expected result as images. Or provide blend file.

Comment: I edited my questions thanks :)

Comment: we still can't see any of your settings. pls provide blend file

Comment: Are u able to open the file?

Comment: yes. So how did you make them "hidden" in some dimensions? please tell us as detailed as possible.

Comment: Like the Black circle is only visible when u zoom in a lot and look under the icing. When i render the image it should not be visible. But it works now with checking Z :)

Comment: Ok, great! Please click the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try checking "combined" and "z":

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris this is how it should be for me. 
Why is this actually the answer? Like why check Z?

Comment: You didn’t check that in your file and as I checked it I thought that was what you want. I think the „z“ makes the „pass“ take the z values of grease pencil take into account for rendering.

Comment: Okay as i thought thanks